# Getting current activity from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I have a thread that listens for a TCP connection. When a connection is made, I would like to basically stop what the current activity is doing, and move to another activity that runs different threads and display a different layout.

For now I would also like to keep that thread running (waiting for a TCP connection).

I can change activity from one to another using startActivity() on an Intent, but that doesn't work while within my thread.

How can I please achieve that behavior?

Thanks a lot,

James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules of thumb of long-running task programming in Android. If you have:

1. A short-running task (thread) that is only used by one Activity at a time then use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
2. A long-running task that should survive Activity's lifecycle and/or is used by multiple Activities (also external to your app), than use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Service is a separate process that is more resilient to shutdowns than Activity.
3. A task that needs to be run based on some external condition like: location changed, network available, etc. Or if you need a periodical data sync or a timer based task, then you don't need to have a task running, just register your code with an appropriate API and OS will call it when appropriate. This is called asynchronous programming and is the preferable option on Android, since it minimizes memory and processor use by only invoking code when it needs to be invoked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those explanation, that is very useful. I need to use a Service or an API then (2 or 3). I am not sure if there is an API that can "wait for a TCP connection". Do you please know how I can find that out? Thanks otherwise! Very helpful!

Comment: Could a service load an Activity? My Service would be to wait for a TCP connection forever. When one happens, then an activity that receives and sends UDP packet would be launched (it has it's own layout as well). Would that work please?

Comment: Do you need to have TCP connection constantly open even when app is in the background? This will drain battery and possibly be expensive on mobile network.

Comment: Yes service can start an Activity. But this is considered extremely bad practice: if user is doing something else (using other apps) than your activity will be suddenly started and current Activity will be put to background. Do you know any app on your phone that behaves like this? In this situation it's best to use notification (sound, led, notification bar). This is done via NotificationManager.

Comment: I am building a VoIP app. So I am waiting for an incoming connection. If a connection is made, I switch to UDP and start sending voice recording and receiving it. So I think yes, it will be open all the time.

Comment: Ha I see. Basically, when I receive a TCP connection, I want to change the layout and put two buttons: "Accept call", "Refuse call". Should I use the NotificationManager or do I need to fully switch the layout, that I am not entirely sure. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You do realize that will not work on most networks since devices are behind NAT and you can not initiate connection from internet towards device. You need some kind NAT traversing technique: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal

Comment: Actually the only time that popping out an activity and covering current activity is acceptable when a call is received. So I guess in your case you could (even must) pop start an activity from the service.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, for now it will be for phones on the same network. I have a server that will be hosted (with users login) afterwards, this is just an intermediary step.

Comment: Would you know how to actually get the service to start the activity? That's the thing I cannot seem to find out, thank you.

Comment: I am actually having an issue, I start the service from my activity class, but then it won't load the layout (set by setContentView(R.layout.main); in the activity class). It runs the code in the service but it seems like it replaced the activity. Any clue please?

Comment: I think I fixed it, I actually needed to make a thread in the service.